# python cli framework that replaces argparse

Tags: python-3.x

I am searching for Python Command Line Framework that will replace argparse and also provide an interactive shell for my tool.

Can anyone suggest a good package which is operating system independent?

```
$ python mytool.py
$ (mytool) -help 
$ (mytool) -version
$ (mytool) -commands
```

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on why you think argparse is not operating system dependent? Also I don't understand how "providing an interactive shell" for your tool is related to argparse? Are you talking about a Python shell or a bash/(t)csh/Windows-cmd interpreter tool?

Answer (score 2):

The best choice for you would be python-cliff. It is built on the top of argparse. Some of its key features are

1. It support interactive console
2. It can list Commands
3. Auto completion

For more information you can refer to its [documentation](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/cliff/).